# How to check Windows remote path exists from Linux command?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, command-line

My Jenkins pipeline runs from Linux machine and I want to check if Windows shared path like - `'\\domain\parent\child\grand-child\` exists or not through shell script.

If same was to run from Windows machine, then following would have helped -

```
if exist <windows-shared-path> echo "Path present"
```

Could you please share linux command to achieve this i.e. if windows shared path exists from Linux machine?

Comment: Is that remote path mounted to the linux machine?

Comment: Try smbclient. If the path is a directory: `if smbclient //server/share PASSWORD -c "cd child/grandchild"; then echo success; else echo nope; fi`. If not, use `ls` instead of `cd`.

Comment: @jesse_b, no it is not mounted. Wanted to check if it is possible without mounting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `smbclient` like this:

```
 smbclient -U'<domain>\<user>%<password>' '\\server\path\to\dir' -c exit && echo exists || echo does not exist
```

I.e. `smbclient` will fail or succeed depending on availability of the given location and return an exit code of `0` or `1`, respectively. By directly issuing `exit` as command, we do nothing on the share itself.

Answer (score 0):

@FelixJN answer did not work for me, `smbclient` with `\\server\path\to\dir` connects to `\\server\path`, not `\\server\path\to\dir` then always success if at least `\\server\path` exists, that said, inspired from this, I used `-D` in addition, well replacing `\` by `/` since else I got `tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME` error, and also escaping `\` for `-U` option:

```
smbclient -U'<domain>\\<user>%<password>' '//server/path/' -D 'to/dir' -c exit && echo exists || echo does not exist
```